# what is the size of common? fortran77

Tags: fortran

i have a problem that how to know the size of the same 'common' which is in different subroutine?

```
program hello

end program Hello

subroutine test()
    real::a(10,10)
    common /ttt/ a
end 

subroutine test2()
    real::b(10,20)
    common /ttt/ b
end
```

i just get the information of the complier..but i don`t know the final size in '/ttt/'?

```
$gfortran -std=f95 *.f95 -o main
main.f95:13:16:

     common /ttt/ b
                1
Warning: Named COMMON block ‘ttt’ at (1) shall be of the same size as elsewhere (800 vs 400 bytes)
$main
```

Comment: Presumably the largest...

Comment: Why do you expect this to work? `a` and `b` are different sizes, and you're attempting to compile them in a manner that requires them to be the same.

Comment: Also, unless you're stuck using legacy code, `common` blocks are incredibly outdated (30 years!) and should not be used.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you're asking/trying to do. Please try to explain more!

Comment: mis-matching COMMON block sizes is "common" enough in legacy code that most compilers support it.  Technically, there's no guarantee.  Some compilers forbid it under some circumstances; e.g. ifort builds with OpenMP enabled will throw a run-time error.

Comment: It is a warning, not an error, you may choose to ignnore when building legace software. But do not write new code like this, do not use COMMON in new code at all.

Comment: Putting `common` blocks inside `.f95` files is a bit like putting petroleum distillate  into an electric car, an odd mixture of C20 and C21 technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size here is the size of the variables stored in the common block. In your case it is the size of the array (`a` or `b`). The array does not have the same size in those two subroutines. That is not allowed and the compiler issues a warning. It is a warning, not an error, and you may choose to ignore it. The code is likely to work OK.

Comment: but if i ignore it, what size the compiler would take? I wonder.... Thanks

Comment: *Why* are you trying to do this?

Comment: @gavinjou If you ignore this, the compiler will *likely* take the larger size, but for the subroutine that declared it smaller only the smaller size will be valid.

Comment: Yes,thanks! I did a test and the result is the same as what you said